# How do I change the date format of a date field?

Tags: 8, webforms, datetime

How to change date format of date field? I'm using webform module. There is no date format field to set it. Also read somewhere that changing default date format of "short" format will do the job, so I changed "Default short date" format, but didn't help.

So how to change date format?

Comment: Good question, on an [older version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFvq7.png) I can clearly see it, but not on a [newer one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V34Bu.png)... either they moved it or removed it.

Comment: Interestingly, in the older & newer version there [is an option under Advanced > Submission display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjxZB.png).

Comment: Yes, field is there, but it doesn't work for me. Selected "Default short date", as you did, changed it's format to "d.m.Y", but on front I'm still getting data in "m/d/Y" format. Saved form, cleared the cache, started new form submission - nothing helps.

Comment: Update: switched to jQuery date picker (General tab -> Date settings -> Use date picker) and it works well - can set custom time format and that's all I need.